# Change code to display image attachment page

Tags: attachments, urls, images

I have this code which displays images with their captions in a list.
On clicking caption, opens image in an attachment page, but clicking on image, opens that image with a dark-gray background. Is there a way to display image on attachment page on clicking on it?? I played alot with it, but no success.

```
$i = 0;
    $rand_id = mt_rand(1,1000);
    foreach ( $attachments as $id => $attachment ) {
        $image_attributes = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $id,'large' );


        $link = isset($attr['link']) && 'file' == $attr['link'] ? '<a href="'.$image_attributes[0].'"  rel="prettyPhoto[pp_'.$rand_id.']"><span class="mosaic-overlay"></span>'.wp_get_attachment_image($id, $size, false).'</a>' : '<a href="'.$image_attributes[0].'"  rel="prettyPhoto[pp_'.$rand_id.']"><span class="mosaic-overlay"></span>'.wp_get_attachment_image($id, $size, false).'</a>';
        $output .= "<{$itemtag} class='gallery-item'>";
        $output .= "
            <{$icontag} class='gallery-icon'>
                $link
            </{$icontag}>";

         if ( $captiontag && trim($attachment->post_title) ) {  //caption display
            $output .= "
                <{$captiontag} class='gallery-caption'>
                " .wp_get_attachment_link($id, $size, true, false, wptexturize($attachment->post_title))  . "
                </{$captiontag}>";
           }

        $output .= "</{$itemtag}>";
        if ( $columns > 0 && ++$i % $columns == 0 )
            $output .= '<br style="clear: both" />';
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. As pointed in the other answer, you should not have prettyPhoto part
2. The link should be changed to utilize the function [get_attachment_link](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_attachment_link)

Basically change this line in your code

```
$link = '<a href="'.get_attachment_link($id).'">'.wp_get_attachment_image($id, $size, false).'</a>';
```

Comment: Mridul it works like a charm, but it doesn't display image name and post title above image on attachment page eg: POSTABC--Image234

Comment: The contents of the attachment page doesn't depend on this code. Please look for the appropriate file in your theme. This might help- http://codex.wordpress.org/images/1/18/Template_Hierarchy.png

Comment: ohk, thanks. I'm not able to find my theme file name in this png.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you should remove the prettyPhoto parts, such as

```
$i = 0;
$rand_id = mt_rand(1,1000);
foreach ( $attachments as $id => $attachment ) {
    $image_attributes = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $id,'large' );


    $link = isset($attr['link']) && 'file' == $attr['link'] ? '<a href="'.$image_attributes[0].'"  ]">'.wp_get_attachment_image($id, $size, false).'</a>' : '<a href="'.$image_attributes[0].'"  ]">'.wp_get_attachment_image($id, $size, false).'</a>';
    $output .= "<{$itemtag} class='gallery-item'>";
    $output .= "
        <{$icontag} class='gallery-icon'>
            $link
        </{$icontag}>";

     if ( $captiontag && trim($attachment->post_title) ) {  //caption display
        $output .= "
            <{$captiontag} class='gallery-caption'>
            " .wp_get_attachment_link($id, $size, true, false, wptexturize($attachment->post_title))  . "
            </{$captiontag}>";
       }

    $output .= "</{$itemtag}>";
    if ( $columns > 0 && ++$i % $columns == 0 )
        $output .= '<br style="clear: both" />';
}
```

Comment: It is still same!

Comment: Meaning the outcome is still the same, or that the code i gave you was 'the same'?

Comment: output is same !